# What condition to break out of loop when enter is hit in standard input in Java?

Tags: java

I want to read from a line of string input word for word (that's why im using a while and scanner.next() instead of scanner.nextLine()). Reading works just fine, but I can't break from the loop cause i can't seem to find a good condition for that. It keeps taking input from the command line. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = null, winner = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            x = sc.next();
            if (!sc.hasNext())
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(x);
            if(StdRandom.bernoulli(1/i))
            {
                winner = x;
            }
            i++;
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(winner);
    }
}
```

I tried various functions but none worked.

Comment: If you want to break the loop when winner is defined, then update `while(true)` to `while(winner == null)`

Comment: i want to break the loop when the input ends: say i input "abc xyz abcd". I want it to stop taking input when I press enter (after abcd)

Besides, winner is defined from the first passing through the while loop (as i is initializes as 1 and the probability of the winner being defined on the first passing is 100%)

Comment: Stop talking after pressing enter means you want to read exactly a single line? Read it with nextLine and then split by whitespace

Comment: I suspect that you mean `1.0/i`, rather than `1/i`, as the latter will be zero for everything after the first iteration.

Comment: how about get whole line with nextLine and split it into words after that? you don't need to run while-loop there, sinceyou have already known the input is end with single line.

Answer (score 2):

Having a `.next()` call before a `.hasNext()` completely defeats the purpose of the `.hasNext()` call.

I would suggest using `sc.hasNext()` as the while condition.

To only read one line of input can be very easily achieved with two scanners.
One to read one line of console input, and another one to process that input.
This has the side-effect, of the input not being processed until the whole line is inputted.

```java
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = null, winner = null;
        final Scanner scl = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 1;
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(scl.nextLine());
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            x = sc.next();

            System.out.println(x);
            if(StdRandom.bernoulli(1/i))
            {
                winner = x;
            }
            i++;
        }
        sc.close();
        scl.close();
        System.out.println(winner);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to read more than one line of input, you can do

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    x = sc.next()
    ...
}
```

And end your input by pressing ctrl-D (on Linux) or ctrl-Z (on Windows) at the start of a new line to signal end of input.

Otherwise, if you want to read only one line, use [C0D3 M4513R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76505411/13963086).

Answer (score -1):

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Press Enter to continue...");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        if (input.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Loop exited.");
```

Comment: i can't afford to do scanner.nextLine() as I will possibly lose words. I use the while loop to read input word for word.

Comment: @oomertaa doing `.nextLine()` does not lose words. It just gives you the whole line as one String.
You can still use it as shown in my answer.
If my answer solved the issue, please mark it as the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can read the whole line and use StringTokenizer to get the tokens and assign them to x while iterating:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = null, winner = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sc.nextLine());
    int i = 1;
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        x = tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(x);
        if(StdRandom.bernoulli(1/i))
        {
            winner = x;
        }
        i++;
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(winner);
}
```

Comment: Is this not the same basic idea that I had?
What are the upsides, compared to my answer (besides StringTokenizer not needing to be closed)?

Comment: The javadoc for StringTokenizer says: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code." - and that's not the most recent documentation, but the Java 1.4 documentation! That's right - StringTokenizer became legacy 20 years ago!